# x86-64 gcc doesn't assign a stack frame for local variable

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, stack-frame, red-zone

I had some problem when I learned about assembly code.

I use "compiler explorer" that is a website that supporting a lot of compiler.

I made a simple code and compiled it as x86-64 gcc.

<C++ code>:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    return sum(3, 4);
}
```

:

sum(int, int):

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    add     eax, edx
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

main:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     esi, 4
    mov     edi, 3
    call    sum(int, int)
    nop
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

As I know, stack presents for local variable and saving return address, etc in x86.

I can't see that anything about "sub rsp, ??" in function prologue. And I can't see "add rsp, ??" in function epilogue, too.

Comment: Maybe because there is no local variable in your code?

Comment: @tofro: main is a red herring and could be omitted from this [mcve].  The question is about `sum`, which does spill its function args to the stack.  (In the red-zone below RSP, instead of reserving more stack space, because it's a leaf function.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : Thanks to you, it was solved clearly!!! Why couldn't I find the posts about this question... I'm so ashamed...

Comment: It helps when you know the answer so you what to look for; I found them by searching on "site:stackoverflow.com red zone gcc stack frame`.  So IDK how easily they'd come up searching on terms like "missing sub", especially if phrasing it as "gcc writing outside its stack frame" didn't occur to you.